# when i try partial search inmy table in Mysql , it gives me Error Empty set (0.00 sec)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

Dears,
when i try to search for an item in my table and this item exits it gives me error Empty set (0.00 sec), so can anyone advice whats wrong with my code

```
//search database for food item
app.get("/search-db", function (req, res) {
    //searching in the database
    let word = [req.query.name];
    let sqlquery = ' SELECT * FROM calorie WHERE name LIKE  '%word%' ';
    // execute sql query
    db.query(sqlquery, word , function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        res.redirect(err.message);//redirect on home page(search page)
    }else
        res.render('select', {Calories:result}); // redirect to List Page with result of Search in our database
    });
});
```

Comment: change the line to: `let sqlquery = ' SELECT * FROM calorie WHERE name LIKE  \'%'+word+'%\' ';`

Comment: like [1](https://society6.com/product/you-saved-my-life_pillow), [2](https://musescore.com/scopianore/scores/6128225), or like the [DJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtfZbj4J71A) ? 